# ASP.NET MVC 2 Tutorial

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I would like to know if there is a tutorial similar to Nerd Dinners but specifically for MVC 2 rather than just the vanilla MVC 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right I have searched and the best tutorial I have found is: 
[MVC Music Store](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Although I found that the tutorial isn't as good as Nerddinner and really skips alot of the explanations that made Nerddinner so good!